# Checking duplicate file version and keeping the latest file with specified pattern only in Python

Tags: python

I have too many pdf files in the folder. I want to remove the old version file automatically by Python only.

The file name is like this:

```
20022021_cap_mp_19_1_col_r1.pdf
20022021_cap_mp_19_1_col_r2.pdf
20022021_cap_mp_18_1_col_r1.pdf
20022021_cap_mp_20_1_col_r2.pdf
20022021_cap_mp_20_2_col_r1.pdf
20022021_cap_mp_21_1_col_r3.pdf
20022021_cap_mp_21_2_col_r4.pdf
20022021_cap_mp_21_2_col_r5.pdf
```

Filename Syntax how file name defined:

```
date_techcode_mp_pageno_editionrevision_fileversion.pdf
```

So I won't just check the edition revision. If it is higher so it keeps the file. If the edition revision is the same then checks the file version. Which file version is high it keeps other delete.

Example:

Condition 1: If the file which name is `20022021_cap_mp_19_1_col_r1.pdf` and it released again its file version changes mean it names like `20022021_cap_mp_19_1_col_r2.pdf`. So the old file `20022021_cap_mp_19_1_col_r1.pdf` must delete and `20022021_cap_mp_19_1_col_r2.pdf` remain in the folder.

Condition 2: If the file which name is `20022021_cap_mp_20_1_col_r1.pdf` and it released again its file Edition version changes For example:-`20022021_cap_mp_20_2_col_r1.pdf.  So the old file` 20022021_cap_mp_20_1_col_r2.pdf`must delete and`20022021_cap_mp_20_2_col_r2.pdf` remain in the folder.

Condition 3: If the file which name is `20022021_cap_mp_21_1_col_r3.pdf` and it released again it's file version changes to `20022021_cap_mp_21_2_col_r3.pdf` and again new version released `20022021_cap_mp_21_2_col_r5.pdf`. So the old file `20022021_cap_mp_21_1_col_r3.pdf` and `20022021_cap_mp_21_2_col_r3.pdf` must delete and `20022021_cap_mp_21_2_col_r5.pdf` remain in the folder.

I have try with not find solution :

```
import os,fnmatch,glob
from typing import Pattern
path=("/temp")
os.chdir(path)
Edition_no=1
r_no=1
file_list=[]
Pattern=('*_'+str(Edition_no)+'_*_*.pdf')
for filname in os.listdir():
    if filname.endswith('pdf'): 
        file_list.append(filname)
file_list.sort()
for file in file_list:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file,Pattern):
        print(file)
```

Comment: Okay... did you also want to ask a question about your goal?

Comment: can you also add what you've tried? did you write any code?

Comment: @AvenDesta please check question again i have post my try code

Comment: what is the `editionrevision` for the file `20022021_cap_mp_19_1_col_r1.pdf`. And please check that Condition 2 is correct

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what is the problem with the code you have tried?

Comment: Problem is this it remove all file. I want this file remain 20022021_cap_mp_01_2_col_r1.pdf and file which name is  20022021_cap_mp_01_1_col_r1 is deleted

Comment: @mkrieger1 My file name is change on every new version i want store that version.

Comment: @AvenDesta edition version  is number syntax: 20022021_cap_mp_19_edition version _col_r1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elegant solution is based on sorting and grouping.

1. Build your filename list (glob, walk, ...)

```
>>> filenames
['20022021_cap_mp_21_2_col_r5.pdf',
 '20022021_cap_mp_19_1_col_r2.pdf',
 '20022021_cap_mp_21_2_col_r4.pdf',
 '20022021_cap_mp_20_2_col_r1.pdf',
 '20022021_cap_mp_18_1_col_r1.pdf',
 '20022021_cap_mp_20_1_col_r2.pdf',
 '20022021_cap_mp_19_1_col_r1.pdf',
 '20022021_cap_mp_21_1_col_r3.pdf']
```

2. Prepare your data to be processed by `groupby` (sort and reverse)

```
from operator import itemgetter
from iterator import groupby

data = [(filename, *itemgetter(0, 1, 3)(filename.split(".")[0].rsplit("_", 3)))
        for filename in filenames]        
data.sort(key=itemgetter(1, 2, 3))
data.reverse()
```

This is what data look like:

```
>>> data
# filename, common prefix, file version, edition revision
[('20022021_cap_mp_21_2_col_r5.pdf', '20022021_cap_mp_21', '2', 'r5'),
 ('20022021_cap_mp_21_2_col_r4.pdf', '20022021_cap_mp_21', '2', 'r4'),
 ('20022021_cap_mp_21_1_col_r3.pdf', '20022021_cap_mp_21', '1', 'r3'),
 ('20022021_cap_mp_20_2_col_r1.pdf', '20022021_cap_mp_20', '2', 'r1'),
 ('20022021_cap_mp_20_1_col_r2.pdf', '20022021_cap_mp_20', '1', 'r2'),
 ('20022021_cap_mp_19_1_col_r2.pdf', '20022021_cap_mp_19', '1', 'r2'),
 ('20022021_cap_mp_19_1_col_r1.pdf', '20022021_cap_mp_19', '1', 'r1'),
 ('20022021_cap_mp_18_1_col_r1.pdf', '20022021_cap_mp_18', '1', 'r1')]
```

3. Group by the common prefix

```
# for demonstration purpose
keep_files = []
remove_files = []

for _, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(1)):
    files = [f[0] for f in group]
    # do whatever you need here
    keep_files.append(files[0])
    remove_files.extend(files[1:])
```

The first element of group is the file you keep while others are files you want to remove:

```
>>> keep_files
['20022021_cap_mp_21_2_col_r5.pdf',
 '20022021_cap_mp_20_2_col_r1.pdf',
 '20022021_cap_mp_19_1_col_r2.pdf',
 '20022021_cap_mp_18_1_col_r1.pdf']

>>> remove_files
['20022021_cap_mp_21_2_col_r4.pdf',
 '20022021_cap_mp_21_1_col_r3.pdf',
 '20022021_cap_mp_20_1_col_r2.pdf',
 '20022021_cap_mp_19_1_col_r1.pdf']
```